# telerik:RadMultiPage visible tab on redirect

Tags: c#, redirect, telerik

I'm using the `telerik:RadMultiPage` in my system, if i leave one tab and click cancel on the next page i am currently using a redirect to return the user to the starting page, but it always resets the tab view to the first tab.

Is there a way to use redirect (or something similar) to 'send' the user to the correct page and make tab 2/3/4 visible?

```
 <telerik:RadTabStrip ID="RadTabStrip1" runat="server" Skin="Vista" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1"
SelectedIndex="0" Align="Justify" ReorderTabsOnSelect="true" Width="600px">
<Tabs>
    <telerik:RadTab Text="Staff Codes" Width="150px">
    </telerik:RadTab>
    <telerik:RadTab Text="Assignments" Width="150px">
    </telerik:RadTab>
    <telerik:RadTab Text="Areas of work" Width="150px">
    </telerik:RadTab>
    <telerik:RadTab Text="Assignment Codes" Width="150px">
    </telerik:RadTab>
</Tabs>
</telerik:RadTabStrip>

<telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView1" runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        **dropdown list
        **dropdown list
        <asp:Button ID="btnAssignmentSearch" runat="server"  onclick="btnAssignmentSearch_Clicked" Text="Search" />
        **gridview
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</telerik:RadPageView>
<telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView2" runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        **dropdown list
        **dropdown list
        <asp:Button ID="btnAssignmentSearch" runat="server"  onclick="btnAssignmentSearch_Clicked" Text="Search" />
        **gridview
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</telerik:RadPageView>
```

this is the aspx page with the radpages and links/buttons (i have thinned it out massivley to just give an example of the page)
The links just go to a 'respone.redirect' in the back end, then on the redirected page i have textbos to make changes to the gridviews on each rad tab, then a submit/cancel button. currently they are like this

```
protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Secure/ListStaffGroupCodesAdmin.aspx", false);
    }
```

and i would like them to redirect back to the correct rad tab not just the correct page.

e.g. if a user clicks edit on tab 3, then clicks cancel on the redirected page they should be sent back to the tabs page with tab 3 visible, but currently tab 1 is always visible.

If this doesnt make sense let me know and i'll try and explain a little better.

Comment: Show me your code ! What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just incase this has stumped anyone else i resolved it like this along with removing the 'SelectedIndex="0"' on the rad tab strip and rad page views

**add page**

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.AssignmentTypeManagerIndex = 3;
        Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Secure/ListStaffGroupCodesAdmin.aspx", false);

    }
```

**Page with tabs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            switch (base.AssignmentTypeManagerIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        RadMultiPage1.SelectedIndex = 1;
                        RadTabStrip1.SelectedIndex = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                        RadMultiPage1.SelectedIndex = 2;
                        RadTabStrip1.SelectedIndex = 2;
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        RadMultiPage1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                        RadTabStrip1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
                    }
            }
            base.AssignmentTypeManagerIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```